# Rails Factory girl how to generate 1-letter strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm new to factory girl and I have an object of class foo that has an attribute bar which is a one letter string. So far I've used the following factory

```
sequence(:bar, 'A') { |n| n }
```

and it worked until I added enough tests to make the string consist of 2 letters, i.e. after 'Z' the next generated string was 'AA'. So my question is how do I make it start over from 'A' again? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try `sequence(:bar, [*'A'..'Z'].cycle) { |n| n }` ? I am hoping it work also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Enumerable#cycle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle) in the following way:

`sequence(:bar, ('A'..'Z').cycle)`

Comment: That's cleaner than Sergio's answer, now I'm in a dilemma which answer I should pick :/

Comment: Yes, I also asked to try that OP and confirm me. Because I am 99% sure it should work.

Comment: @Robert You should pick this solution.

Comment: @Robert: if answers are (near-)identical, pick one posted first. Otherwise, pick one that you think is cleaner/better fits your needs/etc. Also, you can upvote answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps

```
sequence(:bar, 0) do |n|
  letters = ('A'..'Z').to_a
  letters[n % letters.length]
end
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much, can't accept the answer yet :)